# Как редактировать статью из GitLab Wiki в VS Code, чтобы появлялись изменения в локальной википедии

Tags: git, gitlab

Я склонировал репозиторий с GitLab Wiki, запустил веб-движок Gollum и хочу чтобы изменения, которые я делаю в VS Code появлялись в моей википедии локально развернутой. Сейчас же когда меняю что-то в VS Code, ничего не происходит.

Сделал изменения с VS Code:

[image: Сделал изменения с VS Code]

Ничего не изменилось в локальной википедии:

[image: Ничего не изменилось в локальной википедии]